# Apple Script: when moving a file into a folder, is it possible to move duplicates inside that folder?

Tags: directory, duplicates, applescript

I have an apple script which moves all files within a folder into a new folder according to the first 6 characters of the filenames.
If the **folder** already exists, the files get moved into that existing folder instead.
If the **file** already exists in the new/existing folder, the file to be moved into the folder gets a "copy" extension to the filename – which is not in the script, it's a system function ;-)

My question:
Is it possible to move all existing (**duplicate**) files into a subfolder (named "_alt" for example), before the other files get moved within the folder (to prevent the "copy"-extension)? I would like to **keep both files**, the original files and the newly moved files.

Thanks.

This is my existing script:

```
set mgFilesFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose folder…")


(* get the files of the mgFilesFolder folder *)
tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of mgFilesFolder

(* iterate over every file *)
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in fileList
    set this_item to item i of fileList
    
    set this_file_Name to name of this_item as string
    
    set thisFileCode to characters 1 thru 6 of this_file_Name as text
    log thisFileCode
    
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set nf to make new folder at mgFilesFolder with properties {name:thisFileCode}
            
        end try
    end tell
end repeat

set sourceFolder to mgFilesFolder
set destinationFolder to mgFilesFolder

tell application "Finder"
    
    
    
    set the_files to (get files of mgFilesFolder)
    
    repeat with this_file in the_files
        
        set the_name to name of this_file
        
        set the_short_name to items 1 thru 6 of the_name as string
        
        if exists folder the_short_name of mgFilesFolder then move this_file to folder the_short_name of mgFilesFolder
        
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Comment: You can move duplicates without getting "copy" adding, but they will replace the already existing same named files. Just add to end of your **if statement** option **replacing yes**. I recommend you to make backup of original folder before testing my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for.
I would like to keep the original files.